# type cannot be resolved

Tags: java

heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class FirstGui extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public FirstGui() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        button = new JButton("Click for sex");
        add(button);

        label = new JLabel("");
        add(label);

        event e = new event();
        button.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            label.setText("how you can see wors here");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(200, 200);
        gui.setTitle("Title");
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }   

}
```

And it generates a errors:

ActionEvent cannot be resolved to a type    FirstGui.java   /Test/src   line 26 Java Problem

ActionListener cannot be resolved to a type FirstGui.java   /Test/src   line 24 Java Problem

The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (FirstGui.event)    FirstGui.java   /Test/src   line 21 Java Problem

what is wrong with it??? im new to java.

Comment: You need to `import java.awt.event.*;`

Comment: it looks like you're missing some `import` statements or something

Comment: Why do you have 2 public classes in the same source file? Does this code compile? You can only have one public class in a source file.

Answer (score 5):

Import the following:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActionEvent` and `ActionListener` are located into the `java.awt.event` package.

Importing `java.awt.*` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these classes require you to import them.  You can do so by importing everything in java.awt.event:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```

or you may just want to import specifically what you're using:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Remember that it's considered good practice to import individual classes (the latter option) instead of importing whole packages.

If you ever get stuck like this again, looking at [The Docs for any Java Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) will tell you exactly what you need to import with a little diagram that looks like this:

```
java.lang.Object
   java.util.EventObject
      java.awt.AWTEvent
          java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```